# how can I get a list of spreadsheet names from list with spreadsheet links?

Tags: google-sheets

In a spreadsheet, I have a column with URLs to other google spreadsheets. I would like to retrieve the names/titles of the corresponding spreadsheets in the second column. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with XPath and `IMPORTXML`. Try this:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2;"//meta[@itemprop='name']/@content")
```

Where A2 is the link to spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it but get remark that it is empty. Anyway, probably this is the way to go.

Comment: It's working here: please, could you share a copy of your file?